# Flutter Offline Stoarge Webview

Tags: flutter, android-webview, offlineapps, webview-flutter

Can I achieve the appsheet like apps using flutter webview. I have a platform which is used to build microapps. I need to load these microapps inside the flutter container/webview and use the microapps in the mobile. Also the microapps should support offline capabilities when used inside the flutter container in the mobile and sync the data to the actual DB when online

I have taken build of the project and put it inside the assets folder in flutter and load the application in mobile view using webview flutter package.
But I am stuck with offline storage. Using flutter local storage can we manipulate the web app's data when the app is offline and sync the data to the web app's actual DB when online.